# Разбить текст на символы и вывести его в параллельном потоке

Tags: java, android

Предположим, имеется String. Её необходимо разбить на символы и каждый символ по отдельности с небольшой задержкой между символами вывести на экран в параллельном потоке.То есть, нужно добиться эффекта печати текста.

Следующий код набросан программистом по профессии, но он работает некорректно. Как с ним работать или как его подправить, чтобы добиться вышеописанного результата?

```
   import java.util.Timer;
.....
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
private TextView tv3;
....
class Task extends TimerTask {
private string mData;
private int k;
public Task(String data){
    mData = data;
    k=1;
}
public void run() {
    //Данный код выполяется каждые 5 секунд
    if(k<mData.length()){
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                //Вывод строки
                tv3.setText(mData.substring(0, k));
                 k++;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
}
}

....Конструтор Activity{
....
tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
mTimer = new Timer();
//5000 - 5 секунд, str - строка для вывода
String str = "Строчка";
mTimer.schedule(new Task(str), 5000); 
}
```

Comment: Вывести на экран?

Comment: Да. В TextView, например.

Comment: Непосредственно из параллельного потока на экран вывести ничего не получится, так как доступ к UI есть только у одного главного потока.

Comment: Тогда нужно вернуть данные главному потоку, который бы обновлял UI, а затем опять передавал бы контроль параллельному потоку, чтобы тот с задержкой выдал очередной символ главному, и так до конца данных. Я о потоках вспомнил потому, что если делать всё это в главном потоке, то UI будет подвисать из-за Thread.Sleep(). Если же есть метод, не вызывающий остановку выполнения процесса, а просто считающий время, то второй поток тут вообще не нужен.

Comment: Элементарная задача же. В самом примитивном случае можно использовать тот же `AsyncTask`.

Comment: А для разбивки юзать  `toCharArray`?

Comment: Для разбивки строки на символы можно использовать разные средства, в частности и этот.

Comment: Прям для RxJava задачка

Comment: @post_zeew Обновил код в шапке. Интересует Ваше мнение

Comment: @user3807779, По моему мнению, требуемое проще всего реализовать с помощью `AsyncTask`. Если интересует такое решение – могу написать.

Comment: @user3807779, И это, программист не создает активити явно, поэтому конструктор для активити, мягко говоря, смысла не имеет.

Comment: @post_zeew меня устроит любое решение,которое будет кратким и понятным, а главное - рабочим. Не откажусь от примера.

Comment: @user3807779, Вы посмотрите ответ, который Вам дали.

Answer (score 2):

Для обновления UI из разных потоков можно использовать широковещательные сообщения. В AsyncTask в методе onPostExecute надо сделать отправку данных, а в Activity создать внутренний класс расширяющий BroadcastReceiver.

```
//AsyncTask
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result!=null&&result.length()>0){
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject explrObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String text1 = explrObject.getString("text1");
                String text2= explrObject.getString("text1");
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("PROCESS_RESPONSE");
                broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("text1", text1);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("text2", text2);
                context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В нем в методе onReceive принимаешь это сообщение и обновляешь UI. Также нужно зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver в методе onCreate

```
// MainActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // Register receiver
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(RequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
   filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   receiver = new RequestReceiver();
   registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

class RequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "PROCESS_RESPONSE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text1");
        String text2 = intent.getStringExtra("text2");
        updateUI(text1, text2);
    }
}

private void updateUI(String text1, String text2) {
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText(text1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView1.setText(text2);
}
```

Пример в документации: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html