# Как объявить класс

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594763/219218) объявить класс-наследник `AsyncTask`? Какие типы данных указывать в скобках?

Answer (score 4):

```
private class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ...
    }
}
```

Наглядная демонстрация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста: http://collabedit.com/fjgjv . Я целый час смотрел, но это ничего не дало(. (Error:(75, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable RequestReceiver Error:(77, 24) error: cannot find symbol class RequestReceiver Error:(260, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable context )

Comment: @user3807779, Тут все-таки QA, а не форум. Создайте новый вопрос (и подробнее в нем опишите, что не получается).